# Update latest record

Tags: mysql

I have a following mysql query to update my `tblcem_appraisal_log` table

```
UPDATE tblcem_appraisal_log AS tblog
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT ta.id
            FROM tblcem_appraisal_log AS ta
            INNER JOIN tblcem_master_appraisal AS tm ON tm.id = ta.master_app_id        
            ORDER BY ta.id DESC
LIMIT 1) AS source ON source.id = tblog.id
SET tblog.quarter1 = tblcem_master_appraisal.quarter1 WHERE tblog.master_app_id=8;
```

I am getting an error `unknown column tblcem_master_appraisal.quarter1` though column `quarter1` is present in both tables.
What exactly need to put in `SET` to update value from `tblcem_master_appraisal` table.

Comment: Note that enumerated columns are almost never a good idea, and invariably point to a lack of normalisation

Answer (score 1):

You have to select the column in your subselect and use the alias of that table:

```
  UPDATE tblcem_appraisal_log AS tblog
     INNER JOIN (
                SELECT ta.id, tm.quarter1 
                FROM tblcem_appraisal_log AS ta
                INNER JOIN tblcem_master_appraisal AS tm ON tm.id =    ta.master_app_id        
                ORDER BY ta.id DESC
    LIMIT 1) AS source ON source.id = tblog.id
    SET tblog.quarter1 = source.quarter1 WHERE tblog.master_app_id=8;
```

Comment: It is good to specify the alias name `tm` before `quarter1` for better understanding. +1 for correct solution

Comment: Query works but not a single row affected. `master_app_id = 8` is present

Comment: @RagingBull Maybe but it is not nessesary. But i have changed my answer.

Comment: @Shri show sample data please or better create a sqlfiddle.

Comment: @RagingBull perfect suggestion. Otherwise an error is `ambiguous` column

Comment: Jens: It is not necessary. As I mentioned, only for **better understanding** and to remove ambiguity :) @Shri: Try to run the innerquery first and make sure it has valid records.

Comment: @Jens Thanks for your answer, just did little change and it works. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
UPDATE tblcem_appraisal_log AS tblog
 INNER JOIN (
            SELECT ta.id, tm.quarter1 
            FROM tblcem_appraisal_log AS ta
            INNER JOIN tblcem_master_appraisal AS tm ON tm.id = ta.master_app_id 
            WHERE ta.master_app_id=8    
            ORDER BY ta.id DESC LIMIT 1) AS source ON source.id = tblog.id
SET tblog.quarter1 = source.quarter1;
```

Put `where` clause inside `join`